# How do I write a unit test for this method that is called inside a loop?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to test a method using xUnit and Moq.
The `public void DoSomeWork_Verify_GetJsonDataString_is_called()` test is failing. Please can someone let me know what I am missing in the test/mocking. The `GetJsonDataString` is an API call that returns a JSON string.

```
public class A 
{
    private readonly IData _data;
    private readonly IApiCall _apiCall;
       
    public A (IData data, IApiCall apiCall)
    {
        _data = data;
        _apiCall = apiCall;
    }
       
    public void DoSomeWork
    {
        var apps = _data.GetListOfApps(); // test on this method call is passing
        foreach(var app in apps)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.AppId)) continue;
            string jsonString = _apiCall.GetJsonDataString("ApiEndpoint" + app.AppId); 
            // how do I test this method call? Note: I'm not using async, this is just a console app.
        }       
    }
}

//MyTest
public class TestA
{
    private readonly Mock<IData> _data;
    private readonly Mock<IApiCall> _apicall;

    public TestA()
    {
        _data = new Mock<IData>;
        _apiCall = new Mock<IApiCall>;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork_Verify_GetListOfApps_is_called() 
    {
        _data.Setup(x => x.GetListOfApps());
        var sut = new A(_data.Object, _apiCall.Object);
        sut.DoSomeWork();
        _data.Verify(x => x.GetListOfApps(), Times.AtLeastOnce);  // this passes
    }

    public void DoSomeWork_Verify_GetJsonDataString_is_called()
    {
        _apicall.Setup(x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>()));
        var sut = new A(_data.Object, _apiCall.Object);
        sut.DoSomeWork();
        _apicall.Verify(x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);  // Failing
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is your api throwing?

Comment: Moq.MockException

Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock `GetListOfApps` so that it actually returns something for you to loop over. To do that you need to make use of the `Returns` method.

Assuming the method returns a `List<App>` your setup could look like the following:

```
_data.Setup(x => x.GetListOfApps())
     .Returns(new List<App> { new App { AppId = "X" } });
```

Now your method will recieve data to loop over and the method you are trying to verify will be called.

Note that while you are setting up `GetJsonDataString`, you aren't giving it a return value. By default Moq will return `null` but you should probably mock that with a return value as well.

```
_data.Setup(x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>()))
     .Returns("some string");
```

There are also overloads of `Returns` that accept a factory function and will take the arguments passed to the mocked function as input. You can use this if you want/need the return result to vary based on the input parameters.

```
_data.Setup(x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>()))
     .Returns(strParam => "some string" + strParam);
```

Now when you're verifying, I'd advise against using `It.IsAny` *when you can*. Otherwise you are saying that you don't care *how* it's called. Suppose we wanted to verify it actually got called with the mocked value from above (`AppId="X"`) you would do this:

```
_apicall.Verify(x => x.GetJsonDataString("ApiEndPointX"), Times.Once);
```

Now you've got a test that's not just checking whether or not the method was called, but actually validating it got called with the *expected* values.

Side note: there is no reason for your test class to accept parameters in its constructor, especially of type `Mock<>`. You aren't even using them! And technically this should fail to even execute since you don't have an `IClassFixture` set up. You can get rid of the constructor completely (and assign the fields directly) or just remove the parameters:

```
public TestA()
{
    _data = new Mock<IData>();
    _apiCall = new Mock<IApiCall>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, returning a value to loop over worked. Please update _data.Setup(x => x.GetJsonDataString(It.IsAny<string>()))  to  "_apicall.Setup"  where GetJsonDataString is called.  Sorry, I made an edit after you posted.

Comment: Any tips on how to test "if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.AppId)) continue"? Thanks

Comment: Write a new test where your mocked list return value has a single item `new App{ AppId=""}` and then verify `Times. Never`